# Check model from VBScript in PowerDesigner and change selected objects

Tags: vbscript, extending, powerdesigner

I need to check Physical Data Model in PowerDesigner 16.5 from VBScript and change selection of objects, which should be checked, but following test case does not work:

1. I press F4 and create in GUI some saved (persistent) selections named Sel1 and Sel2.
2. I use following code in VBScript as found in documentation:

   ```
   Option Explicit
   ActiveModel.UseSelection fct_CheckModel, "Sel1"
   'Output ActiveModel.GetSelection(fct_CheckModel)
   ActiveModel.CheckModel
   ```

Problem is function call "UseSelection" on model does nothing and last selected Persistent Selection is used , which can be checked with commented line (does not return desired Sel1).

Am i missing something or it is just some bug in PowerDesigner?

Comment: It works for me with 16.5.3... The selection change is taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now i know it is worth to think about upgrade :-)